# Dygraphs does not work with csv file. How to fix it?

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am learning Dygraphs and I am trying to test the sample code on https://dygraphs.com/tutorial.html. The first example with embedded data works perfectly just the same as the graph on the web page. Unfortunately, the second example does not draw anything except the coordinate looks like the figure below. What was wrong with it? (note: I just copied the html code from the page and downloaded files dygraph.css and dygraph.js and placed them in the same folder).

An empty coordinate of a dygraphs example, no drawing for data from a .csv file:

[image: An empty coordinate of a dygraphs example, no drawing for data from a .csv file]

Comment: How are you providing the path to the CSV file? [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ejpg26xq/) is setup with the original example, and a hotlinked CSV file, and it's working like expected (as in the example). Are you getting any console or network errors in your browser's DevTools?

Comment: This is an important note from the link you provided: "Make sure your CSV file is readable and serving from a place that understands XMLHttpRequests! In particular, you cannot specify a CSV file using "file:///" "

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you, FiddlingAway, for your prompt replies. The CSV file was downloaded from https://dygraphs.com and placed in the same folder as the index.html file.

Comment: The index.html content is: <html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="dygraph.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
      src="dygraph.css" />
</head><body>
    <div id="graphdiv2"
      style="width:500px; height:300px;"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    Dygraph.onDOMready(function onDOMready() {
      g2 = new Dygraph(
        document.getElementById("graphdiv2"),
        "temperatures.csv", // path to CSV file
        {}                  // options
      );
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changing "temperatures.csv" to "https://dygraphs.com/temperatures.csv". which means, the local folder does not meet the requirement of "a location accessible via XMLHttpRequests. The original sample works fine because the csv file and the index.html both are on a web server.